# AMPSCRIPT to get Value in JourneyData

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, sms

I have an issue in ampscript to get value in journeyData to Send an SMS. This is my ampscript to check if that field in journeyData has value or not

```
if empty(sObject:field) then
    set @field = "empty"
endif
if not empty(sObject:field) then
    set @field = sObject:field
endif
```

the thing is it's not sending sms because of this line of code eventhough I have a checker

```
set @field = sObject:field
```

if I remove this line and the data that entered the journey has no value for this field an sms will be sent same with data having this value. Any reason why this is happening eventhough I have a checker.

I'm running out of options , any suggestion is a big help thanks!

Comment: Wrap your variable in brackets when using that format. So, set @field = [sObject:field]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where the `sObject:field` data is coming from, but given it’s in the DE used in the journey, try the following script below.

It seems that in the script you wrote, you were trying to do things the other way around. Instead, set a variable first, and then decide what to do with it in case it’s empty or not:

```
%%[
set @field = AttributeValue("sObject:field")

 if empty(@field) then
       <do stuff>
 else
        <do other stuff>
 endif
]%%
```

Reference:

- setting values in AMPscript: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript101.htm
- if/else statements: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I used attributeValue instead of directly assigning the journey to the variable and it worked!